# How to best iterate through a MongoDB database with many levels of arrays and objects?

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, nosql

I'm building a website where I will need to access an object in my database, and use the data in that object to render a specific page. My database has 8 documents, each of which goes multiple levels deep with embedded objects in arrays (example below).

At the moment, I'm able to create a page that sort of digs down a specific path, but that's all I can do. I would like to be able to choose a topic at random, as well as another page that tracks some specific objects, at varying levels.

The issue I've run into seems to be that I can't query the database in any meaningful way to return an object, unless I've already previously gone through it from the top level to whatever level I'm now at.

Here's a snippet of my database. Applied Sciences is the first of 8 documents.

```
{
    "name": "Applied Sciences",
    "description": "",
    "completed": false,
    "category": "Field",
    "resources": [],
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "Agriculture",
            "description": "",
            "completed": false,
            "category": "Field",
            "resources": [],
            "items": [
                {
                    "name": "Agricultural Economics",
                    "description": "",
                    "completed": false,
                    "category": "Field",
                    "resources": [],
                    "items": [MORE OBJECTS]},
                {
                    "name": "Agronomy",
                    "description": "",
                    "completed": false,
                    "category": "Field",
                    "resources": [],
                    "items": [MORE OBJECTS]},
                {
                    "name": "Aquaculture",
                    "description": "",
                    "completed": false,
                    "category": "Field",
                    "resources": [],
                    "items": [MORE OBJECTS]},
```

What I'd like to be able to do, at any point, is tap into ANY object. This could be Applied Sciences, or Agriculture, or Agricultural Economics, or an object in the Agricultural Economics.items array (which I removed for the sake of simplicity, but the objects have the same schema).

My original thought was that I could add a unique ID to each object, but am I right in thinking that a find query would still only execute at a document level?

Comment: I recommend creating a function to get a value or embedded object by path. For example, `getObjectValue(obj, 'items.0.items.2')` would return the object with name `"Aquaculture"`, and `getObjectValue(obj, 'items.0.items.2.category')` would return `"Field"`. You could also support array item query by name, the equivalent for the first example would be `getObjectValue(obj, 'items.Applied Sciences.items.Aquaculture')`

Answer (score 0):

You can query for nested objects, but to your point, find queries will return the entire document, not just the nested object.

You could use [aggregation pipelines](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) to return more specific nested objects. But depending on what you're doing, it may be easier (and in some cases even more performant) to query for the entire document with a simpler find query, then narrow down the results in your programming language of choice.

Depending on how else you're going to use the data, you might want to consider revising your schema to a different data structure so it's not so deeply nested—try to weigh the advantages of structuring your data this way vs. query challenges it may present. The MongoDB documentation has a really helpful section on [modeling tree structures](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/), I suggest reading them and think about how they apply to your use case.

For update operations, read up on [arrayFilters](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/), which will make your life much easier.